# What's the difference between Shamballa and Agartha?

Tags: mythology

What's the difference between Shamballa and Agartha?

I read some articles on the internet about fantasy worlds and I came across these two worlds. I really can't tell the difference between them as they are very similar.

Comment: Three Dog Night never sang about Agartha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have heard the name Shambhala before.  Shamballa, or Shambala, is a mythical kingdom in Hindu and Tibetian Buddhist lore.  Because of the influence of Indian mysticism on western mysticism Shamballa is known in western culture also.  There have been expeditions in search of Shamballa and the name is mentioned in some works of fantasy.

Agartha is the name of a mystical underground city in caves beneath Tibet or at the Earth's core. It is often associated with Shamballa or confused with it.

If you want to know more about them read the online and printed articles, books, etc. you can find about them.  If you want to know if they are different ideas or the same place/idea with different names you might have to do a lot of research.